# Does H170 Pro Gaming motherboard support VT-x?

Tags: motherboard, vt-x

I have an Intel Core i5-6600 and I know this supports VT-x, but I don't know if my H170 Pro Gaming motherboard supports VT-x. I found VT-d in the BIOS but I can't find VT-x anywhere.

Comment: I don't have a source to back it, but VT-d doesn't make much sense without VT-x. Most users can work with VMs just with VT-x, VT-d is an extra. If VT-d is supported, then I'm pretty sure VT-x is too.

Comment: Vt-d and Vt-x are separate features.  A CPU can be support just VT-x or both VT-X and VT-d.  The motherboard supports both since your CPU supports both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does.

> **Intel Virtualization Technology**
>
> When set to [Enabled] a VMM can utilize the additional hardware capabilities provided by Vanderpool Technology.

[H170 PRO GAMING Motherboard Manual](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/H170_PRO_GAMING/E10499_H170_PRO_GAMING_Guide_WEB_only.pdf)

> Previously codenamed "Vanderpool", VT-x represents Intel's technology for virtualization

[x86 virtualization - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization)

*If it still doesn't work in software like VirtualBox, try removing Hyper-V or editing BCD to add boot entry with hypervisor disabled.*